# How To Use an external font TTF file which defines a font in foreign language and then use it in a JRXML file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I am trying to create a pdf document which is internationalized, My specific requirement is to generate a pdf document which has text elements defined in "Marathi" language. I have the TTF file for the font which enables me to see the "Marathi" language, I would like to know how can I let my *JRXML* file know of existence of this "font" defined in the TTF file.

Where should I define the font or keep my TTF file so as I am able to use the font in the `<font/>` element of my *JRXML* file. So as the "Marathi" language text is displayed in the PDF document.

Comment: Depending on you version you should either use font extensions (> 3.7.2) as explained by AlexK or rely on system installed font as described by Saifuddin. Of course font extension is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Font Extensions* mechanism.

You can read this article for more [information](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fonts).

The quote from *JasperReports Ultimate guide*:

> The best way to control fonts in JasperReports is to provide the font
>   files as extensions to the library. Basically, this involves putting
>   True Type Font files in a JAR file, together with an XML file that
>   describes the content of the JAR and the various relationships between
>   the fonts and the locales.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `.ttf` file in class path and specify the font name in `.jrxml` , Optionally Arial Uni.ttf would also work for your case